# Python ValueError. Don't understand error or how to fix

Tags: python, arrays, numpy, dataset

I am following the tutorial here; https://www.analyticsvidhya.com/blog/2018/10/predicting-stock-price-machine-learningnd-deep-learning-techniques-python/#comment-155692

Instead of using the provided dataset I am using one needed for my assignment.

The code used is

```
#import packages
import pandas as pd
import numpy as np

#to plot within notebook
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
%matplotlib inline

#setting figure size
from matplotlib.pylab import rcParams
rcParams['figure.figsize'] = 20,10

#for normalizing data
from sklearn.preprocessing import MinMaxScaler
scaler = MinMaxScaler(feature_range=(0, 1))

#read the file
df = pd.read_csv('C:/Users/Usert/Downloads/stock-20050101-to-20171231/stock-20050101-to-20171231/IBM_2006-01-01_to_2018-01-01.csv')

#print the head
df.head()

#setting index as date
df['Date'] = pd.to_datetime(df.Date,format='%Y-%m-%d')
df.index = df['Date']

#plot
plt.figure(figsize=(16,8))
plt.plot(df['Close'], label='Close Price history')

#creating dataframe with date and the target variable
data = df.sort_index(ascending=True, axis=0)
new_data = pd.DataFrame(index=range(0,len(df)),columns=['Date', 'Close'])

for i in range(0,len(data)):
     new_data['Date'][i] = data['Date'][i]
     new_data['Close'][i] = data['Close'][i]

#splitting into train and validation
train = new_data[:987]
valid = new_data[987:]

new_data.shape, train.shape, valid.shape
((1235, 2), (987, 2), (248, 2))

train['Date'].min(), train['Date'].max(), valid['Date'].min(), valid['Date'].max()


#make predictions
preds = []
for i in range(0,248):
    a = train['Close'][len(train)-248+i:].sum() + sum(preds)
    b = a/248
    preds.append(b)

#calculate rmse
rms=np.sqrt(np.mean(np.power((np.array(valid['Close'])-preds),2)))
rms

#plot
valid['Predictions'] = 0
valid['Predictions'] = preds
plt.plot(train['Close'])
plt.plot(valid[['Close', 'Predictions']])
```

This runs fine until "#Calculate RMSE" when it hits the error.

```
File "<ipython-input-92-1256d885493e>", line 65, in <module>
rms=np.sqrt(np.mean(np.power((np.array(valid['Close'])-preds),2)))

ValueError: operands could not be broadcast together with shapes (2033,) (248,)
```

Using "print(valid.shape)" and "print(len(preds))" as requested returns "(604, 3)" and "248".

Any idea how I change the numbers to fit my dataset as each time I change the numbers I create more errors?

Just FYI;

The dataset I am using has 7 columns named "Date, Open, High, Low, Close, Volume and Name" with 3021 rows of data including headers.

Whilst the one in the tutorial has 8 columns being "date, open, high, low, last, close, total_trade_quantity, and turnover" with 1236 rows including headers.

Comment: what are the shapes of `valid['Close'])` and `preds` ? The error is due to the fact that you are subtracting arrays of different dimensions

Comment: Im not 100% sure being a nooby. I added all the code entered and the provided tutorial incase any of the rest of it answers your question :)

Comment: what happens if, just before the `#calculate rmse` you do a `print(valid.shape)` and `print(len(preds))` ?

Comment: you're surely doing something wrong because I've copy pasted your code in a jupyter notebook with the data [downloaded from here](https://s3-ap-south-1.amazonaws.com/av-blog-media/wp-content/uploads/2019/03/NSE-TATAGLOBAL11.csv) and it works. Edit: the problem then is likely to be in your dataset

Comment: Using "print(valid.shape)" and  "print(len(preds))" returns "(604, 3)" and
"248". I assuming its something to do with how im splitting my data set since there is a different number of rows and columns, however being so new to the topic i'm not sure how to correctly amend them for my dataset (info for my data set in comparison to example dataset in original post).

Comment: if you want, post the dataset on wetransfer or something and send me the link, I will have a look at it, I think it's pretty simple to solve